# How to speed up Ubuntu booting process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, unix

I am a newbie on `Linux`, and I am using `Ubuntu 19.04`, the one under development and about to be released. It happens to be slow during startup, so I want to speed up the `startup process`. I have already disabled all the startup applications, but the `boot` process is still slow. How do I go about it?

Comment: Note: if you run `systemd-analyze` on its own it'll *also* give you a one-line summary of all the boot steps before userspace applications. Example output: `Startup finished in 7.354s (firmware) + 5.167s (loader) + 4.236s (kernel) + 15.680s (userspace) = 32.439s`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do on a newer distro like yours is to use the following tool:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

This will show you all the systemd services that have been started during the boot process and how long it took for each of them to start. Services are different from applications, which are the ones you've most likely disabled. If you can see any service that took too long to start, **but either you or the system doesn't need it to start automatically during boot** - you can disable it:

```
systemctl disable service-name.service
```

**Note:** Before disabling a service you might be interested in debugging why that service is starting too slow.

That way systemd will stop automatically starting that service up during boot and this will shorten your boot time.

An **important** note here is that you need to make sure that the service really isn't need during boot, otherwise you could even break your system. To be sure - google the service first.

Boot process in Linux isn't like Windows - it's simple and most likely a slow boot process means too many services that start at boot (and take too long to start).

---

Other than that you can check what filesystem you use for your `/boot` partition (or `/` if you don't have a seperate one) and make sure that the filesystem is a light and fast one, and that it is also tuned. You'd surely need to read more for this though.

And besides this point I can only suggest checking your hardware - if your OS resides on a slow hard drive - there wouldn't be much you could do about speeding it up. SSD (especailly NVMe SSD) is the fastest storage you can use for an operational system - this would reduce your boot time by a lot.

**Articles you can read**:

1. [Make Linux Boot Faster](https://www.maketecheasier.com/make-linux-boot-faster/)
2. [BootProcessSpeedup @ Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/BootProcessSpeedup) - Ubuntu is Debian-based so you can get more ideas here, however, keep in mind that some might be outdated.
3. [Understanding and using systemd](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-and-using-systemd) - understanding your init process will surely help you a lot with your task.

Comment: Using `systemd-analyze` is definitely the right way to go but I wouldn't be so quick to advocate disabling services wholesale - even if those services are not critical to the boot process. I understand that it's the fastest answer but the user should continue down the troubleshooting chain and diagnose individual programs to see why they're taking longer to init.

Comment: @baelx For disabling I simply mean services like databases (postgres, mysql), web servers and any such services that the user might have installed for testing purposes, but doesn't really use. And databases for example take too long to start and that's completely normal. Going further to debug such cases requires a lot more in-depth knowledge and guessing by this question - OP lacks that knowledge. It is the fastest and simplest way - but unless you're a pretty good enthusiast, sysadmin, or anything like that - it is asking too much.

Comment: That is my own opinion, of course. I do appreciate your point of view and it is completely legitimate. But for a new Linux user - although a good learning experience, it would be really hard and time-investing to debug those cases. Adding a note in my answer nonetheless.